# Management of content without clear cache

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I be sure that my user is using/seeing the latest version of my static content (js scripts, gifs, svgs, etc...) without telling them to clear their cache?

Comment: Google "cache busting in asp.net mvc".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two broad options.

1. Disable caching altogether. That is a reasonable idea for dynamic content but generally poor for static content. So we will ignore this for now.
2. Generate different URLs / querystring for when your static content changes.

There are many possible approaches for option 2, for example:

- https://zoompf.com/blog/2015/01/automatically-optimize-css-javascript-asp-net
- [How to version javascript files in a Bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35901012/how-to-version-javascript-files-in-a-bundle)
- [What is the best way to version javascript files in a huge asp.net legacy project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627382/what-is-the-best-way-to-version-javascript-files-in-a-huge-asp-net-legacy-projec)
- [Autoversioning CSS/JS in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818799/autoversioning-css-js-in-asp-net-mvc)

Additionally, https://github.com/mwrock/RequestReduce is an option I have used in the past that you may want to have a go with.